# College vs Collegiate

Tags: word-usage, differences

What are the differences between `College` and `Collegiate`? Which one to use in which cases? I have also found some other similar pairs like: `Meteor vs Meteorite`, `Human vs Humanoid` etc. Did these words form in the same way or any correlation among them?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the basic expectations of the site is that you consult common references firstl a dictionary, for example, will outline common usages. Please [edit] this information into your question. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: The only difficult one of the three examples is **meteor/meteorite** which is more of a technical definition than linguistic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, this is one great question. The words are corresponding but have a bit of a differentiation.
meteor/meteorite: Meteors are defined as meteoroids that from space enter into the earth´s atmosphere, which accelerates with a huge amount of speed and burn in flames. This differs from a meteorite that even though burning make it to the earth troposphere (
Earth's surface).

Human vs Humanoid: Human means a living being as characterized as human nature and appearance in the physical state. In contrast, a humanoid is an object which has the appearance of human characterism, which means that they aren't humans but have human resemblance. By not exaggerating it could be like Science Fiction. For example .: (Robots who look like humans...)

College vs collegiate: A college is an education or literacy institution compared to school, while collegiate, an adjective describes any Institution which relates or is based on the elements of a college. It follows the characteristics of an educational institution.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't 'collegiate' only an adjective?

Comment: Yes. It's an adjective. I just meant that it's used to relate to an educational institution.

Comment: Sorry the last example wasn't explained so clear!

Comment: I guess my point is that there's no such thing as 'a collegiate'. You should edit to remove the error.

Comment: Why was this question closed?

Comment: I can only guess the question was closed because what they ask is easily answered by a dictionary and there really is no relation among those tree pairs.